# Fitbit api with PHP Curl

Tags: fitbit

I try to access my data via the fitbit api, The Authorization portion work great, I can see my app in my user setting, I have a brand new access_token. But I cannot get any data from it always receive a 400 error.

Here my php code

```
        $url = "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json";

        $auth_header = array("Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['access_token']);

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);             
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_header);   

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $results = json_decode($result, true);
```

$result is always

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2016 14:56:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 579
Connection: close
```

The weird thing even if I remove the header, I always got the 400 error without any error form the fitbit server.

Don't know why ????

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is working code with my project

```
$oauth_profile_header = ["Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['access_token']];                
$url = "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json";

$cu = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $oauth_profile_header);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($cu);
curl_close($cu);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: A big thank for your answer, But I cannot test it anymore, now the first part of the code stop working, each time I call fitbit to get the code, it return only this #_=_. I see my request in my account, If I revoke it, I see the fitbit page to accept the request I click Accept and I'm return to my site with the #_=_ at the end. It was working before, very sad.